# VB.Net: How to add CEFSharp events

Tags: vb.net

Does anyone know how to add events to CefSharp in VB.Net? I want to add an event, so if a page fails to load, it will load an error page telling the user instead of just having a blank white page. I have tried adding the following, with `browser` being `CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser`:

```
Private Sub browser_LoadError(sender As Object, e As LoadErrorEventArgs) Handles browser.LoadError

End Sub
```

But I get `Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.` and I don't know why. I have tried adding the `WithEvents` variable:

```
Private WithEvents Sub browser_LoadError(sender As Object, e As LoadErrorEventArgs) Handles browser.LoadError

End Sub
```

But then I get `'WithEvents' is not valid on a method declaration.`.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `WithEvents` to `browser`:

```
Private WithEvents browser As ChromiumWebBrowser
```

This isn't technically a `CefSharp` question, most just a generic `VB.Net` question.

Comment: Oh, wow... I put it in the wrong place. How did I not see this? Anyway, thanks!